# Android Gmap v2 infowindow click load activity with data based on id of marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a gmap v2 android class that is populating points on a gmap by parsing data from my xml file. My XML file contains 3 things I want:

- Coordinates
- Name
- Description

On marker click I want to see an info window with the Name in it. I can get that. On Infowindow click, I want to start a new activity with the Name and Description in textviews.

I am lost at how I can click on the infowindow to show a new activity with the Description from the corresponding name. I tried creating a class called MapMarkers and then adding each "entry" into it, but it returns a string only and i cannot figure out how to grab just the title from it, but still have the desc available for the next activity:

```
public class MapMarkers {
    private LatLng coor;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public MapMarkers() {
        super();
    }

    public MapMarkers(LatLng coor, String title, String desc) {
        super();
        this.coor = coor;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return coor + title + desc;
    }

    public LatLng getCoor() {
        return coor;
    }

    public void setCoor(LatLng coor) {
        this.coor = coor;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

Here is my for loop where I am getting the data. All the data is there. I can see it with a Log.v(TAG,data.toString());

```
for (XmlDom entry : entries) {
                    XmlDom lon = entry.tag("longitude");
                    XmlDom lat = entry.tag("latitude");
                    XmlDom name = entry.tag("name");
                    XmlDom desc = entry.tag("description");

                    final String firename = name.text();
                    final String firedesc = Html.fromHtml(desc.text()) + "";

                    String geoLon = lon.text();
                    String geoLat = lat.text();

                    String coor = lat + "," + lon;
                    // Log.e("COORS: ", coor);

                    double lati = Double.parseDouble(geoLat);
                    double lngi = Double.parseDouble(geoLon);

                    LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);

                    marks = new MapMarkers();
                    marks.setCoor(LOCATION);
                    marks.setTitle(firename);
                    marks.setDesc(firedesc);
                    mrkrs.add(marks);

                    for (int i = 0; i < mrkrs.size(); i++) {
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(LOCATION)
                                .title(firename)
                                .snippet("CLICK")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.wfmi_icon48)));
                        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                                //Show full description in new activity. 
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
```

How can I keep this description data associated with the map marker so that on click I can pass this data through the intent to the new activity with this data?

I hope that makes sense.... I am kind of lost. :)

EDIT:

Using the MapMarkers class I created, my map points show the correct information when being added to the map:

```
marks = new MapMarkers();
                    marks.setCoor(LOCATION);
                    marks.setTitle(firename);
                    marks.setDesc(firedesc);

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(marks.getCoor())
                            .title(marks.getTitle())
                            .snippet(marks.getDesc())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.wfmi_icon48)));
```

However, when I click on the infowindow, I only get the last "description" in my test message alert window:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                                // Show full description in new activity.
                                fireDesc(marks.getTitle(), marks.getDesc());
                            }
                        });
```

So getting the description from the marker is my issue here. Hope that clears it up.

EDIT EDIT:

Using `fireDesc(arg0.getTitle(), arg0.getSnippet());` Is showing the data, so I need to hide the snippet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiate between different markers in Maps API v2 (unique identifiers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714327/differentiate-between-different-markers-in-maps-api-v2-unique-identifiers)

Comment: @MaciejGórski thanks for the link. I'll give that a shot. I think it is what I am in search of. Didn't come across that looking for help probably due to my title wording! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whatever details you need to the new description activity, in the intent like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("name", "xxx");
i.putExtra("description", "xxxxxx");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks Kavin, I understand that. What I am not getting it how to get the infowindow click to hold the coor,desc and name, so when I click, I get the desc for the corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late. 
I solved the problem by putting the data ID in the ***marker.snippet()***. I've then set the visibility to gone and finally in the ***onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)*** I retrieved it with ***String itemId = marker.getSnippet();***

Hope it helps, also if there's a better solution where I can keep the snippet visible, I will be glad to read it.